# Cannot access serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am not able to access the built-in serverless SQL pool in my Azure Synapse workspace. It says

> You don't have access to the serverless SQL pool, Built-in. To be granted access, contact a Synapse Administrator for this workspace.

In the network tracing, I can see a 401-Unauthorized error when the serverless pool is contacted.

Weird thing, I am a Synapse administrator (in the Synapse RBAC context) and also contributor to the actual Azure resource. I am also Storage Blob Contributor in the connected storage account.
The dedicated SQL pool however is working flawlessly for me.

I already tried a complete teardown of the resource group and re-provisioning via bicep. I also checked the permissions (RBAC roles). There are no managed private endpoints but whenever I try to create one to the sqlondemand endpoint, it says that the private endpoint already exists in an Azure-managed resource group (which sounds reasonable regarding the fact that the Managed vnet is activated).

Any ideas on what's the blocker here?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas to resolve this issue

- Make sure to also assign Storage Blob Contributor also for Synapse managed identity.
- Create a new Synapse instance using the Azure Portal. Test it, and then check the role assignments which were automatically created between the resources. Then check them against your Bicep template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The synapse MI was already explicitly granted the Storage Blob Contributor. I'll check your second suggestion!

Comment: The Bicep-provisioned roles are a superset of those generated by the manual process. Strangely enough, the manually created workspace does not have any auth issues...

Comment: One last idea: Have you tried assigning yourself as the Synapse Active Directory admin? You'll find this setting on the portal under Synapse Workspace > Settings > Azure Active Directory.

Comment: I did not try that yet but I was able to fix the issue by coincidence: I set the `createManagedPrivateEndpoint` property of the defaultDataLakeStorage section in the bicep template to `false` and now it's working (but I don't really understand why tbh).

Comment: Great! Could you edit your question and include the answer?